# hide and show in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax function called login

```
function Login(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/moviereviews/v1.0/index.php/user/adduser/'+$("#loginusername").val(),
headers:  {authorization:window.btoa($("#loginusername").val()+':'+$("#loginpassword").val())},
contentType: "text",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        authorisation = window.btoa($("#loginusername").val()+':'+$("#loginpassword").val()); //create a variable to pass to the cookie
        createCookie('cookie',authorisation,0); //create our authorisation cookie for the client
        alert("Login Successful!");
        $("#loginbox").hide(); //hide the login button
        $("#logout").show(); //show the logout button
        $("#addreview").show(); //show the add a review button
        $("#adminpanel").show();//show the admin panel page
         $("#editreview").show();
           $("#deletereview").show();
        $("#loginusername").val(''); //clear the name box
        $.mobile.changePage("#home" ); //show the menu

    },
error: function (response) {
    var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);

    alert("Error:" + r.error.text);
               }
        });
}
```

At the moment it shoes delete review button but in html it hides it as the user is not logged in,
what I want it to do is when One specific user is logged in show delete button only on the review he has posted not on the others how do I do that with in Ajax
PHP code web service:

```
function deletereview_delete($id=null){{

    // authorization required by the user to post a review
        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        {   
            if (empty($headers['authorization'])) {
              $info->status = 'failure';
               $info->error->code = 15;
               $info->error->text = 'Authorization required';
               $this->response($info, 401);
         }
       }


        $string = base64_decode($headers['authorization']);
        list($username, $password) = explode(':', $string);{   // checking to see if the Authorization string is valid
            $this->load->database();
            $sql  = 'SELECT COUNT(userid) AS records FROM users '.'WHERE authorization = "'.$headers['authorization'].'";';

            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            $data = $query->row();
            if ($data->records == "0") {
                $info->status = 'failure';
                $info->error->code = 19;
                $info->error->text = 'authorization string is not valid';
                $this->response($info, 401);
            } 
    }}
    {
if (!isset($id)){// check if the ID is specified in the URI
    $info->status = 'failure';
            $info->error->code = 11;
            $info->error->text = 'id not specified in URI';
            $this->response($info, 400);
}}
 {  // if the resource exist
        $this->load->database();
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(id) AS records FROM reviews WHERE id = '.$id.';';

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $query->row();
        if ($data->records == "0") {
            $info->status = 'failure';
            $info->error->code = 12;
            $info->error->text = 'id does not exist or have a resource';
            $this->response($info, 404);
        }
 }{   // checking to see if the Authorization string is valid
            $this->load->database();
            $sql  = 'SELECT username from reviews where id = "'.$id.'" and username= (select username from users where username ="'.$username.'" and authorization = "'.$headers['authorization'].'");';

            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            $data = $query->row();
            if ( $data == false) {
                $info->status = 'failure';
                $info->error->code = 19;
                $info->error->text = 'You do not have permission to delete this review';
                $this->response($info, 401);
            } 
    }
$this->load->database();
$sql= 'SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE id= "'.$id.'";';
$query= $this->db->query($sql);
$data->record = $query->row();
$criteria = array('id'=>$id);
$this->db->delete('reviews', $criteria);
$data->rows = $this->db->affected_rows();
$data->message = 'Review has been deleted';
$this->response($data,200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to get a server side flag or variable with a post like

```
 function Login(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/moviereviews/v1.0/index.php/user/adduser/'+$("#loginusername").val(),
    headers:  {authorization:window.btoa($("#loginusername").val()+':'+$("#loginpassword").val())},
    contentType: "text",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            authorisation = window.btoa($("#loginusername").val()+':'+$("#loginpassword").val()); //create a variable to pass to the cookie
            createCookie('cookie',authorisation,0); //create our authorisation cookie for the client
            alert("Login Successful!");
            $("#loginbox").hide(); //hide the login button
            $("#logout").show(); //show the logout button
            $("#addreview").show(); //show the add a review button
            $("#adminpanel").show();//show the admin panel page
             $("#editreview").show();
//here is the code
             if(data.text=='show')
                $('#deletereview').show();
                            else 
                            $('#deletereview').hide();

            $("#loginusername").val(''); //clear the name box
            $.mobile.changePage("#home" ); //show the menu

        },
    error: function (response) {
        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);

        alert("Error:" + r.error.text);
                   }
            });
    /*rough code*/

    }
```

You can also use json(specify dataType if you use).

Comment: But that 'show' what is that, In my HTML at the moment delete review is hidden, but shows when user logged in PHP code allows user to delete the review if they are the one who updated it, so it works in PHP but now I want to hide it

Comment: thats something you echo from server side. You are sending some data to [link]http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/moviereviews/v1.0/index.php/user/adduser/ right? That adduser function returns a json as I see. if you put "show" in "text" field of that json(or create another field) then it would work.

Comment: Oh so do I echo show in the results? But then how would it know that is the user. because I want the user that is signed in, to allow him to delete his review, which it does but then I want those buttons only visible on his posts.